# Why can't I serialize an object using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to serialize a type using the DataContractSerializer and am getting the exception below.  This isn't for an SOA service, but I would still like to use the DataContractSerializer if possible.  I am using .Net 3.5 SP1.

> Type
>   'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry'
>   with data contract name
>   'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post your class definition?

It seems like you are trying to serialize a class which has a field of type delegate, which I'm pretty sure will make the serializer choke on.

Did you decorate your class with the DataContract / DataMember attributes? In 3.5 SP1 there is a default behavior for the serializer that serializes everything public in a class by default if it is not marked with those attributes. Maybe you should explicitely mark each property that needs to be serialized with a DataMember attribute and leave out those that should not be.

Other than that, we would need to see your class definition for more help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible approaches to avoid the error described in http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oshvartz/archive/2009/10/10/passing-event-handlers-over-wcf.aspx